# What is pendingtotal and nicependingtotal in cpp-ethereum?

Tags: transactions, accounts, cpp-ethereum, balances

If I enter `> web3.admin.eth.allAccounts()` in my eth client I get the following answer after it lists my accounts:

```
  },
  nicependingtotal: '21.173 ether',
  nicetotal: '16.168 ether',
  pendingtotal: '0x125d7efa42fd28720',
  total: '0xe060fa8c05ea2720'
}
```

I interpret it as if I had 5 that should be 'credited', is that correct?
How can I find more info about these?

edit : 3 days later, having done no transactions, the pending disappeared, really weird

Answer (score 1):

Your interpretation seems correct.  You can double-check with `eth.pendingTransactions` to see that there is a pending transaction that is sending ~5 ETH to the account.  Pending transactions are those that have not been mined to a block yet.

I assume that "nice" is used because values are usually in hex and wei.  So providing the "nice" values is easier for humans to understand.

The [Homestead Guide](https://github.com/ethereum/homestead-guide) may have information about "nice", but it may take time since there's a lot to document and it is a community and volunteer effort.

Comment: web3.eth.getBlock("pending", true).transactions changes all the time, I can't see my address in it, web3.eth.pendingTransactions returns undefined, might be a geth method

Comment: Yes, eth.pendingTransactions is for Geth; only realized you were using cpp-ethereum after I answered and I'm not sure how to get it for cpp-eth.  (getBlock might only be returning transaction hashes: if so they need to be looked up).

Comment: thought I found a way, but no...